# Adding a single array of an array into an array of a multidimensional array in Excel Scripts/ Javascript

Tags: javascript, office-scripts

looking to add a single array into a multidimensional array or an array of arrays.

for example:

```
Data = [["A","B","C","D"]];

NewData =[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]];

CombinedData = [];

for(i=0; i< NewData.length; i++){
  CombinedData.push(...Data,NewData[i]);
}
```

However the above results in this:
"CombinedData =[["A","B","C","D"],[1,2,3,4],["A","B","C","D"],[5,6,7,8],["A","B","C","D"],[9,10,11,12],["A","B","C","D"]....]"

Where what I am looking for is this:
"CombinedData =[["A","B","C","D",1,2,3,4],["A","B","C","D",5,6,7,8],["A","B","C","D",9,10,11,12],]"

This is in ExcelScripts or office scripts which I know is pretty new but just looking for some sort of direction.

Comment: Hey, I posted an answer, but then I noticed the office-scripts tag.  Not 100% sure if the JS solution I gave will work in office-scripts.  I'm not familiar.  If it doesn't work let me know and I'll take it down.

Comment: Hey @Chris Strickland

From my little experience with OfficeScripts, it's JS powered or at least has JS built into the language most of what I have written is 1:1 with JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to spread both arrays and wrap in in brackets to make a new array.

```js
const Data = ["A","B","C","D"];
const NewData =[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]];
var CombinedData = [];

for(i=0; i< NewData.length; i++){
  CombinedData.push([...Data,...NewData[i]]);
}

console.log(CombinedData);
```

Also, you could just use map instead of the for loop:

```js
const Data = ["A","B","C","D"];
const NewData =[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]];
var CombinedData = NewData.map(x=>[...Data, ...x]);
console.log(CombinedData);
```

Comment: Hey, @ChrisStrickland
This worked, I am going to rephrase my question though because I guess it's two multidimensional arrays... looking at how ExcelScripts stored the row data is as an array of an array... so what I had to do was `var CombinedData = NewData.map(x=>[...Data[0], ...x]);` instead of  `var CombinedData = NewData.map(x=>[...Data, ...x]);`